# Asymmetric video codecs for WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I wish to use different codecs between the sender and receiver. Here's an example:
Alice has an older computer, and it can't do VP9 encoding in hardware, so I want her browser to send H.264 video. She can, however, decode VP9 in software without issues.
Bob, her WebRTC peer, has a modern PC, and can encode VP9 in hardware. So, I wish for his browser to send VP9 encoded video.

Is this possible? I don't mind manually munging the SDP offer for each end, but I can't seem to reliably get this to work. The best I've gotten for asymmetrical video codecs is between VP8 and H.264.

I'm also using a WebRTC abstraction layer called peer.js to assist in signaling, and I'm munging the SDP from that library; I'm not sure if that's causing the issue, or if asymmetric codecs aren't even a thing to begin with...